# Probability that $k$ independent picks out of a set with $n$ elements will form a set no larger than $h$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a set $X$ such that $|X| = n$. Let $h \leq n$, let $x_1, ... x_k$ be $k$ random elements of $X$, picked uniformly **with replacement**. What is the probability that the **distinct** elements in $x_1, ..., x_k$ will be no more than $h$?

More formally, let $Y$ be the smallest set such that, for all $i \in [1, k]$, $x_i \in Y$. What is the probability that $|Y| \leq h$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X= \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$?

Comment: You can assume that, without loss of generality. I don't understand, though, how would the semantics of $X$ affect the size of $Y$?

Comment: I misread the question.  You mean to ask the probability that your $n$ choices include no more than $h$ distinct elements, not the probability that each of your elements is less than $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t\in [ 1,k] $ be the number of distinct elements and  $\{n_i\}$
be the set of number of each distinct element, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^t n_i=k$ and $n_i\geq1$.
Then, the number of ways of picking such $k$ elements equals
$$ \sum_{\substack{n_1+n_2+\ldots n_t=k, \\ n_i\geq 1}}\frac{k!}{n_1!\ldots n_t!}$$

And, there are $\binom{n}{t}$ ways to determine $t$ distinct elements.

Therefore, for all $t\leq h$, we have $$\sum_{t=1}^h\binom{n}{t}\cdot \sum_{n_1+n_2+\ldots n_t=k, \\ n_i\geq 1}\frac{k!}{n_1!\ldots n_t!}$$

The above divided by $n^k$ is the probability.